# Update 120.000 rows, one by one, with C++ in SQLite3 database

Tags: c++, sqlite, unreal-engine5

I'm developing a game using Unreal Engine 5.2.1, C++ and SQLite3.

I want to update multiple rows, one by one, with this code:

```
void UCatalogueGameInstanceSubsystem::InsertMyColourToDatabase(TArray<FMyColour> MyColour)
{
    FSQLiteDatabase* MyDb = new FSQLiteDatabase();

    if (MyDb->Open(*DbFileFullPath, ESQLiteDatabaseOpenMode::ReadOnly))
    {
        FSQLitePreparedStatement* PreparedStatement = new FSQLitePreparedStatement();

        if (PreparedStatement->Create(*MyDb, *UpdateMyColour, ESQLitePreparedStatementFlags::Persistent))
        {
            TArray<FString> Keys;
            Keys.Add("$redRGB");
            Keys.Add("$greenRGB");
            Keys.Add("$blueRGB");
            Keys.Add("$id");

            for (const FMyColour MyColor : MyColour)
            {
                TArray<FString> Values;
                Values.Add(FString::SanitizeFloat(MyColor.RGB.R));
                Values.Add(FString::SanitizeFloat(MyColor.RGB.G));
                Values.Add(FString::SanitizeFloat(MyColor.RGB.B));
                Values.Add(FString::FromInt(MyColor.id));

                if (BindUpdateStatement(PreparedStatement, Keys, Values))
                {
                    if (!PreparedStatement->Execute())
                    {
                        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Failed to update color: %s"), *MyDb->GetLastError());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        PreparedStatement->Destroy();
        delete PreparedStatement;
    }

    MyDb->Close();
    delete MyDb;
}

bool UCatalogueGameInstanceSubsystem::BindUpdateStatement(
    class FSQLitePreparedStatement* Statement,
    const TArray<FString> Keys,
    const TArray<FString> Values) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Keys.Num(); i++)
    {
        if (!Statement->SetBindingValueByName(*Keys[i], *Values[i]))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

const FString UpdateMyColour = "UPDATE MyTable "
        "SET Red_RGB = $redRGB, Green_RGB = $greenRGB, Blue_RGB = $blueRGB "
        "WHERE ID = $id";
```

But it halts the game and it does nothing.

Is there anything wrong with this code? Maybe, I have to create a statement for each row to update.

I think the problem is about the number of rows to update. It there are less rows, it doesn't halt the game.

Comment: *Is there anything wrong with this code?* -- Maybe off-topic, but there are issues with the code, database or no database: `TArray<FMyColour> MyColour` -- This should be passed by-reference, not by value -- `TArray<FMyColour>& MyColour`.  Then this: `FSQLiteDatabase* MyDb = new FSQLiteDatabase();` -- There is no need to use `new` here.  All you need is:  `FSQLiteDatabase MyDb;` and remove the call to `delete MyDb;`.  You are risking a memory leak if anything between the `new` and `delete` throws an exception.

Comment: Can't say much about the API wrapper you are using, but it seems like you are NOT using a transaction around the loop; this will make updating that many rows VERY slow, as each row is updated in its own transaction, and SQLite by default waits for transactions to arrive on disk.

The respective SQLite statements are `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before the loop and `COMMIT` afterwards. (or `ROLLBACK` to roll abck all pending changes)

Comment: `FSQLitePreparedStatement* PreparedStatement = new FSQLitePreparedStatement();` -- Same issue here: `FSQLitePreparedStatement PreparedStatement;` -- no need for `new` and `delete`, again removing the risk of a memory leak if anything throws an exception.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've just copied a piece of code from an example I've found. Do you know any tutorial or book to learn how to work with SQLite3 with C++? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have never worked with SqlLite.  I was commenting on the code in general, and the flaws that the code had.  The bottom line is that local variables, regardless of how "complex" they may be internally, do not have to be created with `new` in C++.  If you were actually creating the db and prepared statements to be used outside this function after the function returns, then yes, there is some justification to be using `new` and `delete` (but still not a whole lot of justification, since there are `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` for those scenarios).

Comment: Another thing to consider, isn't the code itself, but where you run it. If you run it directly in a blocking call, it will likely freeze the main game thread and the app won't respond until the process is done. To make the call async (happening on a separate thread), you can use `AsyncTask` or `FRunnable`, there are tutorials for using them widely available.